# Group by Query - Select row with maximum date

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi I have this scores table, And in my report on front end, I have to display the keyword and url and score for latest scan.

```
CREATE TABLE `scores` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `keyword` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `url` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `score` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `check_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

**Here is my Example Data:**

[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqibZ.png)

```
| id | keyword  | url                  | score | check_date |
|----|----------|----------------------|-------|------------|
| 1  | facebook | https://facebook.com | 10    | 2020-10-21 |
| 2  | facebook | https://facebook.com | 30    | 2020-10-25 |
| 3  | fb       | https://facebook.com | 55    | 2020-10-23 |
| 4  | fb       | https://facebook.com | 20    | 2020-10-24 |
```

My Query

```
SELECT s1.*
FROM scores s1
JOIN scores s2
  ON s1.id = s2.id
WHERE s1.check_date = s2.check_date 
GROUP BY keyword,url
```

It returns correct check_date for a specific keyword, url but score is not according to that date. Please help.

Comment: so you need to select the max (check_date), when grouping by  url, keyword. I don't see the need to self join the table here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use aggregation for this.  A simple method is a correlated subquery:

```
select s.*
from scores s
where s.check_date = (select max(s2.check_date)
                      from scores s2
                      where s2.keyword = s.keyword and s2.url = s.url
                     );
```

If you are intent on using an explicit `join` you can use a `left join`, look for a larger date, and return the rows that have no larger date:

```
select s.*
from scores s left join
     scores slater
     on slater.keyword = s.keyword and
        slater.url = s.url and
        slater.check_date > s.check_date
where slater.check_date is null;
```

Comment: Okay so both queries work, with a slight change in first query.. select max(sw.check_date). and the other one too. Can you please briefly tell me why in second query slater.check_date is null??

Comment: @AShabbir . . . Because there is no larger date for the date in `s`.  Hence, the date in `s` is the largest for that `keyword`/`url` combination.